# How to convert percentage of minutes in java

Tags: java, android

I want to calculate percentage of minutes in java. For eg: 10% of 3 minutes in 30 seconds.

Below is my code. I have a variable `t` which has time in minutes. I want to calculate 10% of time `t` and convert that to milliseconds. How can i do that? `assmt_time10per` is wrongly set to `0`

```
int t = 3; // TIME IN MINUTES
long assmt_time = TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis(t);
long assmt_time10per = (t * 10) / 100;
```

Comment: wrong!! 10% of 3 mins is 30 seconds. but here we get 18000 millisecs which is equal to 18 seconds

Comment: 10% of 3 mins is 18 seconds. what do you mean that it is 30 seconds ?

Comment: @Veer Sam is right

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For `10%`, convert your time in milliseconds and divide by 10.

Your error is here (you divide the time in minutes)

```
assmt_time10per = (t * 10) / 100;
```

It should be (you divide the time in milliseconds you just calculated)

```
assmt_time10per = (assmt_time * 10) / 100;
```

Also, when you divide 2 ints, you get an int as a result, here 3 by 10 is 0.3, it returns 0. If you want 0.3, you need to use doubles and set to a double, ie `double d = (double)t / 10d;`, this would set `d` to `0.3`

**Here is working code for x percents**

```
int x = 10; // desired percentage
int t = 3; // time in minutes
long assmt_time = TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis(t);
long assmt_time10per = (assmt_time * x) / 100;
System.out.println(assmt_time10per);
```

Outputs `18000`

Comment: wrong!! 10% of 3 mins is 30 seconds. but here we get 18000 millisecs which is equal to 18 seconds

Comment: @Veer 10% of 3 minutes is not 30 seconds... 3 minutes is 180 seconds, 10% of 180 seconds is 18 seconds.

Comment: @Veer If you want to transform `3 minutes` into `30 seconds` then do
`t * 10` but it is not 10% and I don't see the point.

Answer (score 0):

I think maybe you're making it more complicated then necessary.

```
double percent=10;
int tm = 3;
double seconds = (tm * 60) / percent;
```

This will give you the percentage in seconds.